# What does the @private annotation actually do in Google Closure JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

When I put a comment above my variable or function with `@private` in it what is it actually doing? I have looked at the documentation but I'm still not sure.

```
goog.provide('myproject');

/** @private */
myproject.foo = "bar";
```

I can still access it when I open up chrome's development tools (myproject.foo). And...

```
goog.require('myproject');

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //this works.
    document.body.textContent = myproject.foo;
});
```

The above code still set's the bodies textContent to equal "bar", even when compiled. So what does `@private` actually do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The access control annotations `@private`, `@protected`, and `@public` are
directives for the Closure Compiler that help developers enforce the
desired level of visibility for properties and functions.

To emit warnings for access violations use the Compiler flag:

- --jscomp_warning=visibility

To emit errors for access violations use the Compiler flag:

- --jscomp_error=visibility

Access control annotations are enforced on a per file basis,
meaning that any properties annotated `@private` or `@protected` may be
accessed anywhere within the same file. Also note that the compiler removes 
these annotations from the compiled code since they are not part of the 
JavaScript language.

### Example

#### file1.js

```
goog.provide('ns1');

/**
 * Global private variable.
 * @private
 */
ns1.global = 'foo';
alert('ns1.global = ' + ns1.global); // OK in same file.


/** @constructor */
ns1.Constructor = function() {
  /** @private */
  this.secret_ = ns1.global;
};

ns1.instance = new ns1.Constructor();
alert(ns1.instance.secret_); // No warning in same file.
```

#### file2.js

```
goog.provide('ns2');

goog.require('ns1');

alert('ns1.global = ' + ns1.global); // Not allowed.

ns2.instance2 = new ns1.Constructor();
alert(ns2.instance2.secret_); // Not allowed.
```

With the flag `--jscomp_error=visibility` set, Closure Compiler emits the
following errors.

```
ERROR - Access to private property global of ns1 not allowed here.
alert('ns1.global = ' + ns1.global);
                        ^
ERROR - Access to private property secret_ of ns1.Constructor not allowed here.
alert(ns2.instance2.secret_);
      ^
```

See [Visibility (private and protected fields)](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#Visibility__private_and_protected_fields_) in the *Google JavaScript 
Style Guide*.

Comment: In closurebuilder I set --compiler_flags="--jscomp_error=visibility" but nothing is changing. No compiler errors.

 Great answer btw! :) Didn't know those resources existed.

Comment: @Saucy, to get the visibility errors/warnings, you also need to set `--compiler_flags="--warning_level=VERBOSE"`

Comment: Thank you very much, @cpeisert ! You've been much help. :)

Answer (score 1):

cpeisert implied this in his answer, but just to be explicit: these visibility annotations don't modify your output at all.

Marking a function as @private does not hide it or make it any less accessible in the resulting code than the Compiler normally would, and any third-party code that you introduce at runtime will be able to invoke such functions.

The only access protection offered by these annotations is against code that you compile in with them.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to use `@private` and `@protected` for a better compression (eg.: minify the property names that aren't used from the outside - in simple optimizations). Well, maybe in the future.